# Select headers in table - method range of object _ global failed - works when run with button? but not stepping through

Tags: excel, vba

When stepping through my code i get error 1004 on this line.

```
Range("tablename[[#Headers],[startheadername]:[lastheadername]]").Select
```

Now the weird thing is, I use it every month without issue via a button.
This error only pops when im stepping through the code.

Answer (score 0):

this works instead

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tablename").HeaderRowRange(1).Resize(, 7).Select
```

The error code involves the words "range of object" which made me think that maybe there was a way to use the object in another manner. my original code was just a simple range reference.

I dont have particular insight into listobjects, i mainly copy pasted and tested. But headerrowrange(1) is the first column header in the tablename, resize(,7) expands it from 1 to 7 and .Select does what it does.

So this new code selects the first 7 table headers without error 1004.

This site got me there https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-excel-tables-code/

Comment: which is annoying as the original code was what i get if i do a capture macro of selecting the headers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.